# update mono on ubuntu

Tags: apache, ubuntu, mono, mod-mono

I had an ubuntu server with mono 2.10.8 apache and mod_mono
I wanted to update mono at ver 3.2.3 so I downloaded the source from github and compile it.

Everithing seems ok in fact from the terminal if I type `mono --version` I get 3.2.3
but if I try to access a website on the server (when I get an error page) it says 2.10.8.

What's wrong?

Note that I have restarted apache after the update.

Comment: you likely installed it in a wrong way, how did you do it?

Comment: I've just checkout the code from github, make and install it

Comment: As it is wrote on this tutorial in "mono" chapter.
http://www.bgsoftfactory.net/run-asp-net-mvc-4-with-mysql-on-linux/

Comment: did you uninstall ubuntu's mono before installing the latest mono?

Comment: No! It was installed. Now I tryed to uninstall it: mono 3 seems to work but I have problem with mod mono. After installation I cannot found /usr/local/bin/mod-mono-server not /usr/bin/mod-mono-server

Comment: Ok the problem was XSP now everything is working